# textbox - textbinding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

Let's say that I have a custom WPF control and couple of textboxes on it.
In code behind of my custom control I have couple of properties which are references to 
objects in other control. For example I have a sth like this

```
public MyClass myObject
    {
        get
        {
            return MyObject
        }
    }
```

MyClass have a property Name. Is it possible to bind property Name to textBox.Text ??

I konow that I can do sth like that in XAML

```
<TextBox>
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="" />
 </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

But how can I pass data from myObject to Path value ??

---

I've been experimenting with bindings but it seems that sometimes my textbox doesn't refresh/update Text property. I mean sometimes textbox refresh(I think) and I see new value but sometimes nothing happens (despite the fact that I modified data )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the DataContext is the same as your Control. The path will be

```
Path="myObject.MyPropery"
```

or for short

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myObject.MyProperty}" />
```

Comment: thanks :) Let's say that I modify myObject.MyProperty. I understand that thanks to data binding my textbox will show new value or maybe I have to refresh textbox?

Comment: As long the property you bind to fires notifypropertychanged in it's setter, you should be fine